# Create a data validation in a cell based on the value in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns in a spreadsheet, both are picked from a drop down list.

Col A is "Do you want more information" - Possible Values Yes\No

Col B is "How did you hear about us" - Possible values are Email\Phone\Other

**Question**: If "No" is chosen in Col A, then Col B's value should be N/A, otherwise the user should be able to choose from the dropdown and pick a value.  Using the following formula, I can get N/A to appear, but the "false" option overwrites any available dropdown values or previously selected values.  So simply put, if Yes is chosen, let user choose a value in the other cell. If No is chosen, show N/A in the other cell.  Thoughts on how I can get this to work?

My current formula that doesn't work (which resides in cell A2):

```
=IF(A1="No","N/A","Select Value")
```

Comment: Even with a formula, you can use Data Validation on the cell to produce the dropdown. However, if you do this, when even if the cell is `N/A`, you still have the dropdown available. Also, if they chose any option from the dropdown, the formula is erased. So even if you change back the Yes to a No, `N/A` won't show again. Are you amenable to VBA for this?

Comment: VBA would be fine!  I wasn't sure if that would complicate the matters too much.  So my only question with VBA - is it something that would run on each cell update in A1?  Or is it something that would have to be run manually like a macro?  Id prefer that it's something that happens automatically..

Comment: This is easy via VBA. Automatically is good. Let me hack together a sample really quickly. :)

Comment: Is [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/) what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Set Cell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
        If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
            Cell.Validation.Delete
            Cell.Value = vbNullString
        Else
            If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
                With Cell.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=ContactMethod"
                End With
            ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
                Cell.Validation.Delete
                Cell.Value = "N/A"
            Else
                MsgBox "Input only Yes or No."
                Target.ClearContents
                Cell.Validation.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

If `Yes` is entered in Column A (note the dropdown arrow):

[image]

If `No` is entered in Column A (note the now missing dropdown arrow):

[image]

If anything else is entered in Column A:

[image]

In addition, it safely deletes the validation if Column A's value is deleted or changed to `No`. This way, there's no way to access the dropdown unless Column A is specifically `Yes`.

Make sure to paste it in the sheet's module (Sheet9 in the screenshot below):

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Thanks. But, man, that stuff you linked to is just insane. Great job with that!

Comment: Nah on second thought, I want to use a function instead... j/k this is great :)  Thanks much, Ill try it out and get back to you\mark as answer.  thx!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, because it is not a complete solution, that will need a litle vba...
Firs ComboBox in A1 (Yes/No), in D1:D3 (Email/Phone/Other), in E1 (NA). Write as source for B1 list Data Validation:

```
=CHOOSE(IF(A1="Yes";1;2);D1:D3;E1)
```

You need VBA, for, at least, delete the value in B1 when the value in A1 changes, and change it to "NA" if A1=No

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for my task.
The code lets us change the data validation in one cell depending on the datavalidated input in the previous one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L21")) Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets(3).Range("L23").Clear
    Select Case Range("L21")
        Case "x": x_projection
        Case "y": y_projection
        Case "z": z_projection
    End Select

End If
End Sub

Sub x_projection()

    Worksheets(3).Range("L23").Validation.Delete
    Worksheets(3).Range("L23").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="y, z"
    Worksheets(3).Range("L23") = "z"

End Sub

Sub y_projection()

    Worksheets(3).Range("L23").Validation.Delete
    Worksheets(3).Range("L23").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="x, z"
    Worksheets(3).Range("L23") = "x"

End Sub

Sub z_projection()

    Worksheets(3).Range("L23").Validation.Delete
    Worksheets(3).Range("L23").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="x, y"
    Worksheets(3).Range("L23") = "y"

End Sub
```